# How to Keep TempData persistent in Mvc Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to keep my TempData persistent in View page in Mvc 4.

following is my code.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        var mappedMenu = '@TempData["CompanyUserMappedMenu"]';
```

i want to use  tempdata value for next request in same view.
I can do this in controller using Keep method but am not able to keep on view.

Comment: Guess why it's called 'TempData' :)

Comment: Use `Session`, instead?